# print from a specific time in a log time

Tags: shell, log-files, time

I wrote a script to print 5 days prior to the end of a log file ! and now I want to change it in some way to print 5 hours prior to the end of the file !

this is the script :

```
for d in \
 $(sed -nre 's/.*\[(..)\/(...)\/(....):(..:..:..) .*/\1 \2 \3 \4/p' thttpd.log | date +%s -f-);
do echo $d >s1; done

time=$(expr 60 \* 60 \* 24 \* 5)
EDATE=`tail -1 s1`
SDATE=$[$EDATE - $time]
sd=`date -d '1970-01-01 UTC '$SDATE' seconds' +"%d/%b/%Y"`
echo $sd
awk -F'[:[]' -v vd=$sd 'BEGIN{ gsub(/\//," ",vd);"date +%s -d \""vd"\""|getline d} {p=$0;  gsub(/\//," ",$2); "date +%s -d \""$2"\""|getline o;if(o>d) print p}' ll.log
```

example of log file :

```
213.64.153.92 - - [26/Sep/2002:00:15:15 +0200] "GET/scripts/..%c0%af../winnt/system32/cmd.exe?/c+dir HTTP/1.0" 404 - "" ""
213.64.153.92 - - [26/Sep/2002:00:15:16 +0200] "GET/scripts/..%c1%9c../winnt/system32/cmd.exe?/c+dir HTTP/1.0" 404 - "" ""
```

Comment: Delete `*24` from `time` didn't work?

Comment: no :((( it should print from 01/Jan/2003/07:55:21
it seems that awk command in last line did not work here !

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion, the GNU date command (found on most Linux systems) can take a date expression:

```
  date --date='today-7 days 0000'   ;; print 7 days earlier than today at 0000

  date --date='26 Sep 2002 00:15:16 -5 hours'  ;; closer to your example
```

This could make your scripting a little easier.

Thus the processing would be: (1) get start date and format it (2) locate point in file, and (3) print.  This can be done in a variety of ways, probably with a simple sed statement on the log file.

EDIT ADDITIION:

Specifically this should work: (not guaranteed to be fully tested but works!)

```
 #! /bin/sh
 set -uh

 filename=/var/log/apache2/access_log

 lastdate=`tail -1 $filename | sed 's/^.*\[//
 s/\].*$//
 s/ .*$//
 s/\// /g
 s/:/ /'`
 newdate=`date --date="$lastdate -5 hours" +"%d\/%b\/%Y:%H:"`
 awk '/'"$newdate"'/,/^$/    {print $0}' $filename

 exit 0
```

Comment: SDATE contains the specific time ,  I run  date --date=' $EDATE -5 hours'
but faced error date: invalid date ` $EDATE -5 hours'

Comment: I'm very beginner ! I didn't get what you mean :((( could you please write for me the script with sed command and whatever that I should write

Comment: I checked that , but couldn't run it . ./111: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
./111: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Edited and made into a script and successfully run.  Again, I cannot guarantee it to be fully tested.

Comment: I checked this , It print the hour from 213.64.56.208 - - [01/Jan/2003:10:14:34 +0100] till 213.46.27.204 - - [01/Jan/2003:12:55:21 +0100] , while it should print from 7:55 till 12:55

Comment: To do this CHANGE %H: to %H:%M: